# Override CSS from external resource

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am building a pagination from NG-Bootstrap pagination component. In that I want to change (actually remove) some CSS which is declared in NG-Bootstrap library. How can I do that without changing the NG-Bootstrap style sheet.

[image: This image shown what I want to ignore]

As shown in the above picture I want to ignore **padding-left:0** which is declared in .pagination. I don't need to add another value for it.I just want to ignore it. Is it possible ... ?

Comment: What about overwriting it with !important ?

Comment: But with !important i can change the value.. i just want to ignore it

Comment: Well you cannot ignore a css, you can override it but cannot ignore a specified element in your css file without changing it

Comment: Why do you want to remove/ignore `padding-left: 0`?
This value is the same (0) as if you wouldn't have defined it all and left it to the browser.

Comment: padding-left: 0 is equals to not write it so you are technically ignore it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, no, you can't ignore a CSS styling rule. But you can override it without altering the NG-Bootstrap style sheet.

You can attach CSS rules to HTML documents in a few different ways, here are the most common:

- **Link to an external stylesheet** by adding a `<link>` tag to the `<head>` section of your HTML document:

  `<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" />
  </head>`
- **Embed the CSS** into your HTML document with a `<style>` tag:

  `<style>
      background-color: blue;
  </style>`
- **Add the CSS inline** to individual HTML elements directly with the `style` attribute:

  `<div style="background-color:gray;"></div>`

And depending on which way you do it, different styles will be applied depending on their precedence. Inline takes precedence over embedded, and embedded takes precedence over a linked stylesheet.

For example, if you specify a gray background on a particular element inline, and specify a blue background on that same element in the embedded style section, inline wins and the background will be gray.

So for your situation you could either embed the CSS or put it inline on the elements you want to change. Doing either of those will override what's in the NG-Bootstrap style sheet without altering it.