# How to fix inline coding in html for site map button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website and the user wants the site map to be a bar at the bottom of the screen with a button kinda built in so that when you click it a site map will slide down or up and then allow the user to click it again and make it go away.

I have the coding for it to go up but once you click it i cant get the button to follow so you can click it again. It just goes behind the site map and is gone. I have to use the coding inline due to the people who designed this site before made the css over 10000 lines long and when you try changing it there is always conflicts and the hosting company is no help on the fix. so i found that putting it in the html coding is the only way to overwrite the crazy css they created.

```js
function footer() {
  var footerH = $('footer');
  var fH = footerH.height();
  $('.fTab').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
    $('footer').slideToggle(500);
  });
}
footer();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fTab" style="width: 100%; height: 3em; position: absolute; bottom: 0; display: block; background: #ffffff; color: #000000; line-height: 4em; text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;">Site Map</span>
<footer style="position: absolute; display: none; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 30%; background: #ffffff;">
  test
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ns16twzq/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#smBtn', function(){
  $('#siteMap').css('height', '100%');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
  $(document).on('click', '.active', function(){
   $('#siteMap').css('height', '100px');
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteMap" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; left: 0; bottom: 0; background: #333; transition: all ease 0.3s;">
  <button id="smBtn" style="margin: 10px auto; display: table; background: #fff; padding: 10px; border-radius: 4px; border: none; transition: all ease 0.3s;">Site Map</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works great! last question on how to keep the text hidden under it till you press the site map button

Comment: same concept.. you can use various ideas... may i know why you want to hide the text? how you need exactly

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#smBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('.siteMap').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.siteMap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #333;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.siteMap.active {
  height: 100%;
}

#smBtn {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: table;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="siteMap">
  <button id="smBtn">Site Map</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but the issue is i need to have the css coding part of the html (Inline). this is due to the hosting website has a premade css that they apparently wont let use change.

Comment: You're talking about [CSS precendence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753419/8767826). You just need to add Rajasekar's CSS to a `style` tag on the elements that have those respective classes

Comment: how would I add the .sitemap.active to the style tag?

Comment: You can't do pseudo-selectors inline, but you can embed them into the HTML document by adding a `style` tag in the `head` section, and that will also override whatever they have written in the external CSS file that you aren't allowed to modify